# `text-overflow: ellipsis;` behaves different in <a> than in <p>

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a text like this:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.`

Usually `text-overflow: ellipsis;` puts the `...` at the end of a text line like this:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elit...`

But in my case the viewed text is this:

`Lore... dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.`

When i use this CSS:

```
p, a {
  max-width: 400px;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;

  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

I rebuild it in a CodePen (http://codepen.io/DerZyklop/pen/cDKFh) and figured out, that the ellipsis ellipsis behaves differently in `<a>` than in a `<p>`. With the newest version of Chrome i see this result from my CodePen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCQoO.png]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You should also post your CSS in your question as it's vital to what's going on.

Comment: Question is this phenomenon ONLY in chrome or also in other browsers?

Comment: Good question - confirmed this does not happen in IE11, however the overflow ellipsis doesn't work at all!

Comment: @CBauer, I got the ellipsis to show in IE10 by adjusting the `max-width`

Comment: @j08691 thats why i added it in a CodePen.

Comment: And if CodePen ever goes away or is inaccessible? And is it really that hard to add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: @ThomasE. since my reduced example-snippet is written for webkit, it only occurs in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @j08691 okay. your right. i added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm not completely sure why, I do have a solution.

I think that because `p` by standard is a block element, and `a` an inline element, the way `overflow: ellipsis` is handled differs.

To solve this, just add `white-space: nowrap;`, causing the text to remain on 1 line. Using webkit-only css is bound to give problems in other browsers.

```
p, a {
  max-width: 400px;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  display: block;

  white-space: nowrap;

  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

Edit: After looking into it a bit more, I've found out why it differs in the first place. Text-overflow works when the text overflows it's container (hence the name). Only a block element can have a set width and height, making only block-elements susceptible to any form of overflowing.

This is why it will work the same on both elements when they get a display block (so that they're both block elements, which an `a` element isn't by default), and they get their width and height set. In this case the height isn't set, but due to the `white-space: nowrap;` the element knows it shouldn't go to the next line, and all text overflows on the right, since it can't go to a new line.

In addition to that, and quoting [@Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31582/gareth) (see the comments under my answer, and his own answer):

> "why it's happening" is because you're using a property display: -webkit-box that doesn't have any fixed behaviour. There's no documentation on it because it's from an old specification and it's not a property that's supposed to be used.

Comment: Your‘e right. It works by adding `white-space: nowrap;` AND REMOVING `display: -webkit-box;`. Which btw. makes

```-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;```

obsolete. 

Thanks a lot for that! But unfortunately that’s just the fix and not the answer to my question "why is this happening?". 

What i try to find out is: Is this simply a bug by webkit, or by definition of ellipsis, or is there is any logic behind it, somehow..

Comment: As stated in the first line: I'm not completely sure why. If I find out, I'll update my answer. There is nearly always a logical explanation, so I'll try to find it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does this explain the problem enough for you?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, "why it's happening" is because you're using a property `display: -webkit-box` that doesn't have any fixed behaviour. There's no documentation on it because it's from an old specification and it's not a property that's supposed to be used.

Comment: I gave `display: -webkit-box;` to <p> AND <a>... so i expected to see at least the same unwanted behavior on both elements. Whatever.. it works, and @Gareth [explained that there is no fixed behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24889682/1537751) for `-webkit-box`. I’m done here. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The property causing the difference in display is

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

Since this property only exists in an [older version of the Flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/), you should probably remove it. Unless there is a specific reason you have it in there?

EDIT: It looks like you're trying to limit the number of lines in the block [using an unsupported Webkit property](http://dropshado.ws/post/1015351370/webkit-line-clamp). This is probably a bad idea, as unsupported properties can change their behaviour at any time without notice.

That said, there [aren't many good ways to achieve that effect](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) without Javascript

Comment: Your’e right. It’s caused by `-webkit-box`. The reason why i use it in my example, is that on the same page there is quite the same case of application, but with 3 lines. So, i can use Sander Koedood’s example with `white-space: nowrap;` and without `display: -webkit-box;` for a one-liner. And thanks to your css-tricks.com link i found [this solution](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/) for multi-liners. I’ll try this. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, great! ...i just figured out, that apparently it only occurs to one-liners. And since `-webkit-box` is a older version of the specification, i don’t even want to understand the one-liner issue anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` inside the `<a>`:

```
<a href="#"><span>Raspberry Pi and Synology NAS for XBMC and BitTorrent. The tv-show automation plans.</span></a>
```

[see the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpxmz)

Although, not sure what `display: -webkit-box;` does. But it seems to have a bizarre behavior. Try to use `display: block` instead.

Comment: Thanks lante! It works as well as [Sander Koedood’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24889988/1537751). But unfortunately it’s not the answer to the question "Why?". But i know now, that the issue only occurs, when i use `-webkit-box`. Your example works because span doesn’t get the `-webkit-box`.